# How do you get horses in Minecraft for PS4?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My friend plays Minecraft on Xbox 360, and he can get horses, donkeys and all sorts of different items.

I have Minecraft on PlayStation 4, and cannot find some of the things I see on the Xbox 360 Edition.

How do you get horses in the PS4 version of Minecraft?

Answer (score 2):

It really all depends on the world seed. You might have spawned on a world where you won't find any of those types of animals or the right biomes unless you travel pretty far, as the game is procedurally generated.

If you want an easy way to play in a world with those animals, play creative mode and spawn the exact ones and amount that you want wherever.